# Non-termination of types in Martin-Löf's Type:Type?

Tags: type-theory, functional-programming, dependent-types, curry-howard

In the pre-history of dependent type theory, Per Martin Löf
introduced a calculus that is in some sense the simplest dependent
type theory and the most general form of impredicative polymorphism.
It is often referred to as ***Type:Type*** because the kind ***Type*** is
itself of type ***Type***.  Unfortunately, it is inconsistent as a
logic. This was discovered by Girard in his famous dissertation [1],
who managed to express the Burali-Forti paradox in ***Type:Type***.
Various people have analysed, generalised and simplified Girard's
analysis, see e.g. [2, 3]. This analysis seems to involve showing that
non-terminating terms can be typed.

I have a question about non-termination: do we get non-normalisation ***at
the level of types***? By that I mean, is there a type $T$ such that the
reduction relation $\rightarrow$ used, explicitly or implicitly, to
define equality of types, gives rise to an infinite reduction sequence
$$
   T \rightarrow T' \rightarrow T'' \rightarrow \cdots?
$$

[1] J.-Y.. Girard, Une extension de l'interpretation fonctionelle de
Gödel a l'analyse.

[2] T. Coquand, A New Paradox in Type Theory.

[3] A. J. C. Hurkens, A Simplification of Girard's Paradox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: For $\mathrm{Type}:\mathrm{Type}$, non-termination at the type level is trivial. You can take a constant $X:\mathrm{False}\rightarrow \mathrm{Type}$. Then if you take the inconsistent term $\bot : \mathrm{False}$ you have
$$ X\ \bot : \mathrm{Type}$$
Which is non-terminating at the type level. You might complain that this has a *head normal form*, which isn't what usually leads to inconsistency in type theory. In this case you can remember that 
$$ \mathrm{False}\equiv \forall X.\ X$$
and so
$$ \bot\ \mathrm{Type}:\mathrm{Type}$$

Which has no head-normal form. In general, in this system the types and terms are so intertwined that the non-termination always seeps at the type level.

However, there is another system, called $U^-$, also described by Girard in his thesis, which was discovered to be inconsistent by Coquand (A New Paradox in Type Theory). *This* system is terminating at the type level, as it only has $\mathrm{system}\ F$ types at the *kind* level, and we know that terms are normalizing in that system (also a result of Girard!).

This means that non-termination at the type level is **not necessary** for having an inconsistent pure type system (a fact that I found out somewhat painfully after having proven an open question while depending on this fact).

Comment: This is super interesting @cody, as I'm in fact trying to compare type theories where types may diverge with type theories where they don't. I wasn't really aware of $U^-$.

Comment: It's an interesting subject! The thing is that usually what is more interesting is the *equational theory* at the type level. Normalization (confluence + termination) can give you good properties, but at the *term level*, you are really interested in termination, as this corresponds to cut-elimination (and implies consistency). There is some interesting work around this theme by Dowek and Werner: http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~werner/publis/moduloJSL.pdf

Comment: Thanks @cody for pointing me towards "Proof Normalization
Modulo". Looks interesting.  I don't think it'll apply to my case,
because the types I'm trying to define are quite non-standard. They
should embed conventional dependent types though. So cut-elimination
modulo should find some manifestation in my setting.

Comment: It might be of interest that there is a dependently typed version of deduction modulo, **$\lambda\Pi$-modulo**. Here is a paper which briefly describes it: https://who.rocq.inria.fr/Gilles.Dowek/Publi/pts.pdf

Comment: Cody, do you know if reduction modulo is implemented in real provers, interactive or automated? For me as an outsider it's a bit hard to work out exactly what rule systems are being use in which working provers.

Comment: Well I do know that there is a nifty implementation of $\lambda\Pi$-modulo: https://www.rocq.inria.fr/deducteam/Dedukti/ Other than that, you might want to have a look at the really nice CoqMT system, that has similar motivations: http://pierre-yves.strub.nu/coqmt/

Comment: Thank you. It seems that deduction modulo is too new to be at the heart of established provers like Coq, Isabelle or Agda yet.