# Importance of indexes in Type(i) in calculus of inductive constructions

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory, type-checking, dependent-types, coq

So I am reading about the calculus of inductive constructions. And I see [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual006.html#sec167) and [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual006.html#sec160) that there hidden indexes that the user does not know about in the $Type$ sort. It says that they are instantiated with proper values at the time of type checking. I am wondering, what is the importance of this? Looking at the rules it seems like I could just as well have not specified the indexes and for the user nothing would ever be any different.

So what difference would the user see if I simply had the rules $Type : Type$ and $\frac{E[Γ] ⊢ T : Type \,\,\,\, E[Γ::(x:T)] ⊢ U : Type}{E[Γ] ⊢ ∀ x:T,U : Type}$ in place of the rules that talk about the indexes?

Comment: `Type : Type` makes the system inconsistent. You can find references in http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12929/example-of-a-false-proposition-when-assuming-type-type/12933#12933 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19065/non-termination-of-types-in-martin-l%C3%B6fs-typetype